# How to extract the supported locales from an Android APK?

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering

Using aapt like so:

```
aapt dump badging my.apk | grep locales
```

Gives output like this:

```
locales: '--_--' 'de' 'nl' 'sv'
```

Not clear to me that those locales are fully supported by the APK or if only some localization exists within the APK code or a supporting library.

I have also considered using apktool to extract the strings.xml files.

Any ideas on what is the best general approach?  Code needs to run on GNU/Linux.

Comment: "Not clear to me that those locales are fully supported by the APK or if only some localization exists within the APK code or a supporting library" -- you would need to come up with a definition of "fully supported". "I have also considered using apktool to extract the strings.xml files" -- that would not necessarily cover all possible definitions of "fully supported". "Any ideas on what is the best general approach?" -- ask the author of the app what locales they support.

Comment: By "fully supported" languages, I mean the languages that the app is designed to be used in.  I _could_ ask the APK provider what languages are supported, but I'm trying to automate the language support detection process as much as possible.

Comment: I meet the same issue. It seems the locales extracted from aapt dump is not correct , and want to know where it is from. There is no locales config in manifest.